# Firebase database design for an order management app

Tags: firebase

I'm familiar with SQL, but I'm unfamiliar with NoSQL and Firebase. I need help designing an `Order` table for the following use case

Description:
1) Users can create orders
2) Once order is created, employees can update the record as they work on them

Requirements:
1) As a user, I want to view all of **my** orders
2) As an employee, I want to view all orders and work on them

I tried doing this on my own, but I feel that my approach is not optimal. I expect the `Order` table to be large, so I want to get the design correct.

According to https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data, "redundancy [is necessary] for two-way relationships". I'm not sure if this is what I eventually need to do, or is there a better solution

This is my `Order` table

```
/oders
  /{{ orderId }}
    ..
    userId: {{ userId }}
    status: "received"
  /{{ orderId }}
    ..
    userId: {{ userId }}
    status: "packed"
  /{{ orderId }}
    ..
    userId: {{ userId }}
    status: "shipped"
```

With this design, I can only filter by `orderId` but not `status` or `userId`

Currently, at the application layer, when I need to filter by `status` or `userId`, I would still fetch all `Order` records from Firebase and let the application only show the ones I need

Comment: "With this design, I can only filter by orderId but not `status` or `userId`". You can order/filter on status with `ref.orderByChild("status").equalTo("received")`

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thank you! This is exactly what I need..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> With this design, I can only filter by orderId but not status or userId.

You can order/filter on status with:

```
ref.orderByChild("status").equalTo("received")
```

You might want to have a look at the Firebase documentation on [ordering and filtering data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data).